# PHP parser to scrape data error

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-crawler

I'm trying to code a php parser to gather professor reviews from ratemyprofessor.com. Each professor has a page and it has all the reviews in it, I want to parse each professor's site and extract the comments into a txt file.
This is what I have so far but it doesn't excute properly when I run it because the output txt file remains empty. what can be the issue?

```
<?php     
set_time_limit(0);

$domain = "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com";
$content = "div id=commentsection";
$content_tag = "comment";
$output_file = "reviews.txt";
$max_urls_to_check = 400;
$rounds = 0;
$reviews_stack = array();
$max_size_domain_stack = 10000;
$checked_domains = array();


while ($domain != "" && $rounds < $max_urls_to_check) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($domain);
    $found = false;


    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName($content_tag) as $tag) {
        if (strpos($tag->nodeValue, $content)) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    $checked_domains[$domain] = $found;
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        if (strpos($href, 'http://') !== false && strpos($href, $domain) === false) {
            $href_array = explode("/", $href);

            if (count($domain_stack) < $max_size_domain_stack &&
                $checked_domains["http://".$href_array[2]] === null) {
                array_push($domain_stack, "http://".$href_array[2]);
            }
        };
    }


    $domain_stack = array_unique($domain_stack);
    $domain = $domain_stack[0];
    unset($domain_stack[0]);
    $domain_stack = array_values($domain_stack);
    $rounds++;
}

$found_domains = "";
foreach ($checked_domains as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $found_domains .= $key."\n";
    }
}


file_put_contents($output_file, $found_domains); 
?>
```

Comment: Use something simple like this - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ jquery style parsing of pages. Would make it simple to manage. Btw, i could not find any `div` with `id=commentsection` in the page that's why could not post a solution.

Comment: Your title had 3 mistakes! It's parser, not phaser and it's scrape not scrap. And PHP, not PhP.

Comment: Take out the error supressor!

Answer (score 0):

> This is what I have so far but it doesn't excute properly when I run it because the output txt file remains empty. what can be the issue?

It gives empty output since there is a lack of array variable initialization.

1. Main part. Add an initialization of variable:

   ```
   $domain_stack = array(); // before while ($domain != ...... )
   ```
2. Additional. Fix other warnings and notices:

   ```
   // change this
   $checked_domains["http://".$href_array[2]] === null

   // into

   !isset($checked_domains["http://".$href_array[2]])

   // another line
   // check if key exists
   if (isset($domain_stack[0]))  {
     $domain = $domain_stack[0];
     unset($domain_stack[0]);
   }
   ```